# jquery client validation with systemjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, systemjs

I'm trying to create inline validation with systemjs loader and ASP.NET. When i loaded libs as bundles, everything works fine, but when I use module access, client validation not working.

**Here is my loader:**

```
import 'jquery'; 
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'jquery.validate';
import 'jquery-validate-unobtrusive';
import 'jquery-validate-additional-methods';
```

**systemjs config:**

```
...
map {
 ...
            // vendors
            'jquery': 'bower:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'jquery-ui': 'bower:jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
            'jquery.validate': 'bower:jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js',
            'jquery-validate-unobtrusive': 'bower:jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js',
            'jquery-validate-additional-methods': 'bower:jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js',
 ...
}
```

I tried to use jquery-validate-unobtrusive as global lib:

```
meta: {
...
'jquery-validate-additional-methods': { format: 'global' }
}
```

but neither worked...
In console of browser I receive no error.

Where is problem please? Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? There are a few mistakes here that can be easily rectified.